# How can I copy value from column on first row per user_id to to second row for same user_id

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following pyspark dataframe:

```
+-------+---------------------+---+----------+--------------+
|user_id|             product | rn|Product_Mo|First_Purchase|
+-------+---------------------+---+----------+--------------+
| 246981|6 month subscription |  1|         6|          null|
| 246981|12 month subscription|  2|        12|          null|
| 249357|6 month subscription |  1|         6|          null|
| 249357|3 month subscription |  2|         3|          null|
| 243532|6 month subscription |  1|         6|          null|
| 243532|3 month subscription |  2|         3|          null|
| 257345|6 month subscription |  1|         6|          null|
| 257345|2 month subscription |  2|         2|          null|
| 256355|6 month subscription |  1|         6|          null|
| 256355|12 month subscription|  2|        12|          null|
| 246701|6 month subscription |  1|         6|          null|
| 246701|12 month subscription|  2|        12|          null|
| 254082|6 month subscription |  1|         6|          null|
| 254082|12 month subscription|  2|        12|          null|
| 239210|6 month subscription |  1|         6|          null|
| 239210|12 month subscription|  2|        12|          null|
| 247518|6 month subscription |  1|         6|          null|
| 247518|12 month subscription|  2|        12|          null|
+-------+---------------------+---+----------+--------------+
```

I need to capture that value for Product_Mo where rn = 1 and copy that to the First_Purchase where rn = 1 as well as rn = 2.
This will allow me to later perform a groupby on First_purchase and count all first and second purchases where 6 month subscriptions are purchased first.

The resulting dataframe should look like:

```
+-------+---------------------+---+----------+--------------+
|user_id|             product | rn|Product_Mo|First_Purchase|
+-------+---------------------+---+----------+--------------+
| 246981|6 month subscription |  1|         6|             6|
| 246981|12 month subscription|  2|        12|             6|
| 249357|6 month subscription |  1|         6|             6|
| 249357|3 month subscription |  2|         3|             6|
| 243532|6 month subscription |  1|         6|             6|
| 243532|3 month subscription |  2|         3|             6|
| 257345|6 month subscription |  1|         6|             6|
| 257345|2 month subscription |  2|         2|             6|
| 256355|6 month subscription |  1|         6|             6|
| 256355|12 month subscription|  2|        12|             6|
| 246701|6 month subscription |  1|         6|             6|
| 246701|12 month subscription|  2|        12|             6|
| 254082|6 month subscription |  1|         6|             6|
| 254082|12 month subscription|  2|        12|             6|
| 239210|6 month subscription |  1|         6|             6|
| 239210|12 month subscription|  2|        12|             6|
| 247518|6 month subscription |  1|         6|             6|
| 247518|12 month subscription|  2|        12|             6|
+-------+---------------------+---+----------+--------------+
```

I haven't yet figured out how to capture that value for Product_Mo where rn = 1 and copy that to the First_Purchase where rn = 1 as well as rn = 2.  The Product_Mo where rn=1 could change in subsequent loops. So I need to copy that value whatever it may be. It won't always be a 6.

I am hoping this makes sense. Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `first` function over the `Window` partition by `user_id` and order by `rn`.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

w = Window.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('rn')
df.withColumn('First_Purchase', first('Product_Mo').over(w))
```

Comment: Is first a function to be imported? ```NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 from pyspark.sql import Window
      2 w = Window.partitionBy('p_paid_user_id').orderBy('rn')
----> 3 df.withColumn('First_Purchase', first('Product_Mo').over(w))

NameError: name 'first' is not defined```

Comment: just import pyspark functions